# My azure storage unique namespace

Tags: sql, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to move some tables from SQL to Azure Table Storage.
I created an MVC Website with the default authentication. I successfully connected it to my Azure SQL database. Now I want to use the table storage for authentication too, instead of the SQL database.
The problem is, I cannot find my storage account's unique namespace. What, where is that namespace?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the 'storage account's unique namespace'? Could you give an example?

Comment: On this link ([link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/)) writes: "Your storage account provides the unique namespace for your storage resources", under "Introducing the Azure Storage Services" section. I think an unique namespace it is something like this: "ElCamino.AspNet.Identity.AzureTable;
". The site: [link](https://identityazuretable.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20Mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a table URL, for example 'http://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/mytable', the 'myaccountname' will be the name of your account. Storage account names must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and may contain numbers and lowercase letters only. The storage account name must be unique on the Azure service. A list of storage accounts your own and more information about them can be found in the Azure Portal.

More information on authentication for tables can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx). Manipulating and authenticating access to your tables are features built into the storage client libraries which are available in a variety of languages. Since you mention MVC, you might want to check out the [.Net storage library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net).